# jQuery check if element is visible inside scrollable div

Tags: jquery, scroll, visible

Ok so I use the following code to check whether an element is visible on-screen.

```
(function($) {

/**
    * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
    * Licensed under the MIT license.
    * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
    *
    * @author Sam Sehnert
    * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
    *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
    *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
 */

$.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t            = $(this),
        $w            = $(window),
        viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top          = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

  return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

};

})(jQuery);
```

However, I would like to use this piece of code so that it checks whether it is visible inside a scrollable element. Specifically the main tag which I used for my main content. How would I go about changing this code so that it works for my scrollable element?
I'm not quite sure what to do. I've already tried changing $w variable to $('main') but that seems to behave odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is really old and in the time that jQuery was still a thing, but nowadays it seems that Javascript has an Intersection Observer API specifically meant for this purpose.

See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 1):

> However, I would like to use this piece of code so that it checks whether it is visible inside a scrollable element.

The plugin is limited to detecting whatever is a direct child of body. That pretty much makes any nested element undetectable to the plugin. See this [explanation](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible#limitations).

Comment: I see, so this is a limitation that hasn't yet been possible?
Is there any other way I could achieve what I want to achieve or am I stuck? Perhaps a different plug-in that does support it?

Comment: I don't know of any plugins of that particular function off hand, but I do recall there's an [article](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery) that plugin is based on. Perhaps reading that article will lead you to a better understanding and one step closer to your objective. In the meantime, I'll try to dig up an old project that was based on visibility and scroll.