# Checking if an element is visible within a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, viewport

First off, this may be considered a duplicate question - however no answer was provided to the one I found when searching:
[jQuery check if element is visible inside scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843489/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-inside-scrollable-div)

I can't seem to find a solution for checking if an element is visible within a parent div that has a scroll bar, there are obviously ways to do this with the offset being from the parent element, but I was looking whether there was an all around solution that would check each of the same selector wrapped up as a plugin so it can be checked constantly.

The current plugin I am using is limited to the actual window viewport and I don't believe it's possible to alter it to work for a scrollable div.

Current code:

```
;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));
```